# ¿Cómo encontrar el punto de intersección entre dos series de valores?

Tags: r, regresión-lineal

Quiero utilizar dos columnas de mi `dataframe`, `height` y `temperature`, como lineas espaciales. No conozco mucho de estos paquetes pero encontré la forma de hacerlo con una de las variables. Que debería cambiar en el código para incluir `height` como valor de y `y` no solo tener valores de `x` en temperatura y que funcionen como coordenadas?

El código que utiliza una variable

```
a = basedata$Tmax
b = radiosond$Temperature
SL1 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(a),a)), "A")))
SL2 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(seq_along(b),b)), "B")))
```

Muestra de los data frames

```
   Height Temperature                Date
    1   2541      293.35 1998-02-16 21:07:00
    2   2558      292.75 1998-02-16 21:07:00
    3   2591      291.65 1998-02-16 21:07:00
    4   2625      290.65 1998-02-16 21:07:00
    5   2654      290.15 1998-02-16 21:07:00
    6   2683      289.65 1998-02-16 21:07:00

     height     Tmax     Tmin
1   2500 290.8035 283.9201
2   2550 290.3135 283.4301
3   2600 289.8235 282.9401
4   2650 289.3335 282.4501
5   2700 288.8435 281.9601
6   2750 288.3535 281.4701
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kriouz, hace unos días publicaste una pregunta similar a ésta no llegué a responderla, te iba a proponer dos soluciones, una es usar herramientas de GIS (que veo es lo que estás pensando) y la otra más sencilla es usar regresiones lineales. Un tema importante, si se tratara de dos funciones lineales el punto de intersección es único y fácilmente calculable, como en este ejemplo tenemos una recta y otra linea con una función no determinada el punto que vayamos a encontrar va a ser siempre una aproximación, y dependiendo del calculo puede no ser único. Veamos:

#### Usando herramientas GIS

Por empezar voy a generar unos datos de ejemplo, solo voy a trabajar sobre `Tmax` para hacerlo más sencillo, el procedimiento con `Tmin` es exactamente igual.

```
# Df. De temperaturas de función lineal
lineales <- structure(list(Tmax = c(290.8035, 290.3135, 289.8235, 289.3335, 
                        288.8435, 288.3535), height = c(2500L, 2550L, 2600L, 2650L, 2700L, 
                                                        2750L)), .Names = c("Tmax", "height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                   -6L))
# Df de temperatura medida función no lineal
medidas <- structure(list(Temp = c(293.35, 292.75, 291.65, 290.65, 290.15, 
                                   289.65, 289.15, 288.65, 288.36), height = c(2541L, 2558L, 2591L, 
                                                                               2625L, 2654L, 2683L, 2693L, 2702L, 2708L)), .Names = c("Temp", 
                                                                                                                                      "height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Con esos datos (`lineales` y `medidas`) armamos los objetos `SpatialLines` que representan los distintos segmentos entre cada punto de cada `data.frame`, y por último con [`gIntersection()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-22/topics/gIntersection) tenemos la función que calcula la intersección de las dos líneas. Con [`coordinates()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.2-5/topics/coordinates) obtenemos el punto o eventualmente los puntos si hay más de una intersección (coordenadas `x` e `y`).

```
library("rgeos")
library("sp")

l1 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(lineales$Tmax, lineales$height))), 1)))
l2 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(medidas$Temp, medidas$height))), 1)))
punto.inter <- coordinates(gIntersection(l1, l2))
punto.inter

         x        y
1 288.8611 2698.199
```

El resultado del ejemplo nos dice que el punto se encuentra en (288.8611, 2698.199), lo podemos verificar gráficamente:

```
plot(lineales)
points(medidas)
grid(5, 5, lwd = 2)
lines(l1, lwd = 3, col='red')
lines(l2, lwd = 3, col='blue')
points(punto.inter[1],punto.inter[2],pch = 8)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si se llega a ver, pero el punto de intersección está graficado como un asterisco y podemos ver de manera visual que parece coincidir con el puntos 288.8611 y 2698.199

#### Regresión lineal

La otra forma más sencilla que te comentaba es usar directamente  regresiones lineal para hacer una aproximación a la "función" que gobierna de cada linea y luego calcular la intersección de ambas. Lo interesante es que no necesitas ningún paquete adicional. Esta idea la tomé prestada de [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114703/finding-where-two-linear-fits-intersect-in-r) pregunta. Con los mismos datos anteriores, podemos hacer:

```
m1 <- lm(height~Tmax, lineales)
m2 <- lm(height~Temp, medidas)
cm <- rbind(coef(m1),coef(m2)) 
# Calculamos intersección
punto.inter <- c(-solve(cbind(cm[,2],-1)) %*% cm[,1])
punto.inter

[1]  288.8742 2696.8657
```

Vemos que obtenemos unas coordenadas bastante parecidas al método anterior, no estoy familiarizado con el paquete `rgeos`, pero imagino que calcula la intersección a partir de las rectas entre los dos puntos de una línea y los dos de la otra, la regresión lineal seguramente encuentre una intersección más cercana al comportamiento general de cada línea y por consiguiente más real. ¿Que método a usar? dependerá del comportamiento de la función no lineal si es relativamente estable, sin distorsiones la regresión lineal puede funcionar muy bien, por otro lado el método de  calcular la intersección de los dos segmentos que se cruzan es más sencillo de "visualizar".

Comment: Gracias, probaré las dos soluciones, era justo lo que buscaba.